# Shiny server on virtual machine

Tags: r, ubuntu, shiny, shiny-server

I configure an Ubuntu VM in oracle VM in a windows server. I want to install shiny server in this machine so I made the following steps in the terminal:

```
sudo su - \ -c "R -e \"install.packages('shiny', repos='https://cran.rstudio.com/')\""
sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
wget https://download3.rstudio.org/ubuntu-12.04/x86_64/shiny-server-1.5.6.875-amd64.deb
sudo gdebi shiny-server-1.5.6.875-amd64.deb
```

After that what command I need to open/run the server? I tried to type in the web browser `http://10.10.88:3838` but it is not working.

I tried in the terminal `sudo systemctl start shiny-server` but nothing happening nothing opened or in terminal

if I type `sudo start shiny server` I receive this error:

```
start: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
```

Comment: *but it is not working*. Can you be more specific? Do you see the shinyserver homepage, or a *page not found* error? are the sample apps greyed out? do you connect through a proxy? have you authorized http traffic in your VM? Btw: isn't this IP adress weird, with only 3 numbers?

Comment: @agenis thank you. the ip is something I found from a youtube video. Maybe it is different in local host. For authorized http traffic I can access other pages of web so I guess it is ok? Yes I use proxy but I don't think this is problem. I can't see anything no homepage or page not found error or the sample apps greyed out.

Comment: You mean you don't know where to find the IP of your VM?

Comment: @agenis maybe it is one issue. Yes. I would like to open the server into localhost

Comment: @agenis also if I run sudo start shiny-server I receive this error start: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using ? Have you heard about systemd ?
 (And not directly linked to your question : may be you can consider using docker rather than VM .. )